# Data grid mandatory validation message does not show properly in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Please refer attached video.

[Vedio](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11pj86tdBHA0XPBIY0-dYqkp7XEeBnx0u)

Expected result - validation does not show with newly added row

Actual result - once a row triggered with a validation it shows in newly adding rows too

This is my source code for add new row button.

```
  public newRowClicked(){
    debugger
    // create new empty row
    var row:entities.DataRow = new entities.DataRow()
    row.fields = JSON.parse(this.template)
    row.fields.forEach(f => { f.value=null })
    this.dataSet.rows.push(row)
  }
```

HTML

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="table-row">
  <div *ngFor="let header of columnHeaders" [ngStyle]="{'width': (100/(columnCount+1))+'%'}" class="table-cell">
    {{header.headerText}}
    <span *ngIf="header.isRequired" style="color:red">*</span>
  </div>
  <div [ngStyle]="{'width': (100/(columnCount+1))+'%'}"></div>
</div>

<!-- FIELDS -->
<div *ngFor="let row of dataSet.rows; index as i">
  <app-data-row-view
          [field]="field"
          [disabled]="disabled"
          [formSubmitted]="formButtonClicked"
          [isEditMode]="true"
          [dataRow]="row"
          [columnCount]="columnCount"
          [index]="i"
          (deleteRowClicked)="deleteRowClicked($event)"></app-data-row-view>
</div>

<!-- CONTROLS -->
<button *ngIf="!disabled" (click)="newRowClicked()" class="btn btn-sm">New Row</button>

<!-- <button style="margin-left:3px" *ngIf="!disabled" (click)="fromCsvClicked()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">From CSV</button> -->
<button class="to-csv-btn" style="margin-left:3px" *ngIf="dataSet.rows.length>0" (click)="viewAsCsvClicked()" class="btn btn-sm">To CSV</button>
<button class="to-json-btn" style="margin-left:3px" *ngIf="dataSet.rows.length>0" (click)="viewAsJsonClicked()" class="btn btn-sm">To JSON</button>
```

and This is the create a row in data grid source code

```
  public addToGrid(){

    // creating the row
    var row: entities.DataRow = new entities.DataRow()
    this.field.dynamicSectionFields.forEach(f => {
      row.fields.push(f)
    })

    // pushing to the list
    this.dataSet.rows.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row)))

    console.log(this.dataSet)

    window.localStorage.setItem("ds", JSON.stringify(this.dataSet))
  }
```

Comment: i think this line make it show error:
`row.fields.forEach(f => { f.value=null })`
Try to remove it and try again.

Comment: @FahadHassan https://streamable.com/a4cgg

Comment: Will you also include your `html` template code also in your question's post?

Comment: You still missing some parts in your question. You still missed to include your `app-data-row-view` component html and ts. Please organize component wise code in your question. Other wise how can we know that from where your that alert is coming and what conditions you have there